# subfigure in latex not in right position

Tags: latex, subfigure

I use subfigure and \hfill to set two subfigures next to each other, I want figure (d,e) become next to each other and figure (f,g) next to each other in the same line. But they are not in the same line. This my latex code:

```
  \begin{figure*}[ht] 

   \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[height=0.45in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture1a.png}  }
  \label{fig1b}
  \hfill

  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics [height=0.45in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture1b.png}}
  \label{fig1c} 
  \hfill

  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[height=1.2in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture1c.png}  }             \hfill
  \label{fig1d} 


 
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[height=.8in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture2.png}}
       \label{fig1a}
    
   \hfill

  \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[height=.8in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture3.png}} 
       \label{fig1e}
     
          



    \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[height=.88in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture4.png}}
      \label{fig1a}
       
              \hfill
 \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[height=.88in]{figures/ch3Ex2Picture5.png}}    
       \label{fig1e}
    \caption{Illustration examples}
  \label{Ex2fig3}  

 \end{figure*}
```

code here

Answer (score 0):

This should look more like this, note the use of `\textwidth`, the placement of the labels and also the line-breaks:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
  \centering
  \subfigure[\label{line1a}]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*0.3]{figures/line1a.png}}
  \hfill 
  \subfigure[\label{line1b}]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*0.3]{figures/line1b.png}}
  \hfill 
  \subfigure[\label{line1c}]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*0.3]{figures/line1c.png}}
  \\  % next line
  \subfigure[\label{line2a}]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*0.45]{figures/line2a.png}}
  \hfill 
  \subfigure[\label{line2b}]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth*0.45]{figures/line2b.png}}
\end{figure*}
```

I would also in almost all cases use the `\centering` and play with the numbers to improve the layout. The most important and obvious thing is to use `width` and not `height` for horizontal placement.